# Publishing different versions of a library version on pypi

Tags: python-3.x, pypi, python-wheel

I just have some general questions on how pypi works. So I would like to publish a library and I have a whl file and a tarball. But I noticed this isn't all that is usually done.

Considering the example: https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.0.3/#files

1) It looks like there is a different whl file for different OS? Does this mean I need to build on every single OS and publish a different one for each? How are these different? Could I build one whl file on windows and have it run on linux?
2) I believe the difference between a whl and a tar is that the tar is just the source code and it may require the installer to have some compiler depending on which library. Is this true? Whl gets around this problem, is that right?

Thanks

Comment: It does! but follow up question. So let's say my library has pandas as a dependency, which has modules written in C. Does that mean I also need to do the same and have a different wheel per OS and Python version?

Comment: No. Wheels themselves don't include dependencies, they only declare dependencies. You may have one universal wheel with binary dependencies — `pip` when installing your wheel on every platform will decide which binary dependency to download and install. In the examples linked above: I publish one wheel for SQLObject but `pip` will download different binary wheels for SQL backend drivers.

Comment: Thank you, that does answer my question!